# can't take member of base class from derived class. C++

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes. Base - `Animal` and derived `MyDog`. I want to change the `ageOfAnimal` from the `setAge` method and then display changed value from derived class - `MyDog`

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Animal
{
 public:
 int ageOfAnimal = 0;
 int setAge(int age) {
    ageOfAnimal = age;
    return ageOfAnimal;
 }
};

class MyDog: public Animal
{
 public:
    void getInfo() {
    cout << ageOfAnimal;
    }

};

int main()
{
   Animal *animal = new Animal;
   animal->setAge(20);
   MyDog myDog;
   myDog.getInfo();

   return 0;
}
```

Output: 0

Why can't I get 20? Is this even posible?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for answers but what i want is to change the state of ageOfAnimal property from different objects

```
class Animal
{
  public:
  int ageOfAnimal = 0;
  int setAge(int age) {
    ageOfAnimal += age;
    return ageOfAnimal;
  }
}

class MyCat: public Animal
{
 public:
  void getInfo() {
  cout << ageOfAnimal;
 }
}


class MyDog: public Animal
{
 public:
     void getInfo() {
     cout << endl << ageOfAnimal;
    }
}
int main() {
 myDog dog;
 dog.getInfo();
 MyCat cat;
 cat.getInfo();
}
```

output: 
20
20

but what i want to see it's 20 21. How to do this?

Comment: It's because you have created second object of type `MyDog` which has it's own copy of variable `ageOfAnimal`. Try do `Animal* animal = new MyDog()`; and then `animal->setAge(20);` and `animal->getInfo();` this should work :)

Comment: `animal` and `myDog` are different entities. What's wring with `MyDog myDog; myDog.setAge(20); myDog.getInfo();` ?

Comment: how can I take changed value then? I just want to change state of base class and take that state in derived class.

Comment: You have two short samples in above comments, try to play with them, you should get it when you try.

Comment: Important to remember that `myDog` is an `Animal` instance by virtue of the inheritance, so `setAge` can be called on it, you don't have to have a base class instance of `Animal` to use it.

Comment: Imagine if a program could only ever have one `int`, and every definition gave you the same `int`. That would be *unusable*. *Each object* has it's *own* value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usage code there are two different objects: `Animal * animal` and `MyDog myDog`. Both objects have their own instances of `ageOfAnimal`: changing it in one object does not modify the second object (which is the expected behavior).

**1.** As `MyDog` is derived from `Animal` one could simply:

```
MyDog myDog;
myDog.setAge(20);
myDog.getInfo();
```

**2.** If you want `ageOfAnimal` to be global for all instances of `Animal` you should make it a [static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

**UPDATE**

To reflect the updated question: one can put `getInfo` into `Animal` class. Default age for cats and dogs can be then specified in the constructors.
Even better way would be to specify age in `Animal` ctor and use [constructor initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for `MyDog` and `MyAnimal` ctors.

```
class Animal
{
public:
   int ageOfAnimal = 0;
   int setAge(int age)
   {
      ageOfAnimal += age;
      return ageOfAnimal;
   }
   void getInfo()
   {
      cout << endl << ageOfAnimal;
   }
};

class MyCat : public Animal
{
public:
    MyCat()
    {
        setAge(40);
    }
};

class MyDog : public Animal
{
public:
    MyDog()
    {
        setAge(20);
    }
};

int main()
{
   MyDog dog;
   dog.getInfo();
   MyCat cat;
   cat.getInfo();
}
```

Output:

```
20
40
```

Or if you want age to be shared between all objects, make it a static member as suggested earlier:

```
class Animal
{
public:
   static int ageOfAnimal;
   int setAge(int age)
   {
      ageOfAnimal += age;
      return ageOfAnimal;
   }
   void getInfo()
   {
      cout << ageOfAnimal;
   }
};

// Initialize age
int Animal::ageOfAnimal = 0;
```

Comment: what if i have Animal, MyDog, MyCat clasess and i want to increment ageOfAnimal property. So when i create MyCat object ageOfAnimal in Animal class will be 20, then i create MyDog, ageOfAnimal will be 21 and so on.

Comment: It seems OP needs `Animal *animal = new MyDog; animal->setAge(20); animal->getInfo();`

Comment: @EduardFedoruk please make it clear what is it exactly you want to achieve, why can't you achieve it, what did you try to achieve it. Then put it in the question. People are not telepathic (un)fortunately :)